# Is there any way to connect to oracle db using simple c++ not vc++ or proc

Tags: c++, mysql, oracle, g++

I am struggling to connect to oracle db using GNU C++.Is there any library which I have to install to connect to oracle db using simple c++ (oops).

Please provide me some sample code as well, this is new for me. Appreciate your help.

I asked a similar question before but forgot to mention that I am not using vc++ and proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need the oracle C++ libraries (OCCI) from oracle. You can find them here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Google "Oracle OCCI tutorial" and you should find pretty much everything you need.

Comment: hi I hope installing  Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications 
 instantclient-basic-win32-11.2.0.1.0.zip (51,458,190 bytes) will suffice. I am working on windows os

Comment: You also need the sdk (Software Development Kit) - "instantclient-sdk-win32-11.2.0.1.0.zip"  - the "basic" gives you the libraries to link to, the SDK gives you the header files to include in your code.

Comment: Hi Brian , I tried using this but cannot able to connect to db . i am using MinGw compiler on windows os , Eclipse ide.Can you please provide me some example as well. Tired of getting errors

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/). It supports several database backends, including Oracle, MySQL, Postgre, ODBC, etc. Using this library would make it easier for you to migrate your application to a different DB, if necessary.

There's a code sample [here](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html). And several more peppered in the documentation.

Comment: HI Emile , will this work on windows os as well, i am using mingw compiler and eclipse ide.

Comment: I've only used it on Linux so far. The documentation talks about compiling it under Windows here: http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/structure.html . You might be able to compile it under MSYS+Mingw using CMake or the makefiles. The SOCI users mailing list archive is located here: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=soci-users . You can search in that archive here: http://sourceforge.net/search/?group_id=121480&type_of_search=mlists ,